# Why Transformation.switchMap(anyLiveData) isn't fire when i change the value of "anyLiveData"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I will hope that when i call to "addPlantToGarden()" passing respect "plantId" parameter then fire the "observers" "Transformations.switchMap(plantName)" but that doesn't happen, what is the error?

```kotlin
private val plantName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    val plant: LiveData<Plant> = Transformations.switchMap(plantName){plantId ->
        plantRepository.getPlant(plantId)
    }

    val isPlanted: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.switchMap(plantName){plantId ->
        gardenPlantingRepository.isPlanted(plantId)
    }


    fun addPlantToGarden(plantId: String) {
        plantName.value = plantId
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

These are a few things to consider:

**1. Check your Repository**

Make sure your `plantRepository.getPlant(plantId)` returns LiveData. Since methods from Repository are executed in background, I prefer encapsulate the function using this:

```
liveData {
    // some async process (e.g. HTTP Request)
    emit(/*your value*/)
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata

**2. Check your Observer**

Are you observing on a correct view lifecycle owner? If your ViewModel is inside a Fragment, make sure to do this:

```
viewModel.plant.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
    // action
})
```

instead of:

```
viewModel.plant.observe(this, Observer{
    // action
})
```

And make sure to **observe first** before trying to change your `plantName` value.

**3. Start with a simple case**

I have no idea how you changed your `plantName` value. But try from a simple hardcoded/mock value first, for example:

```
plantName.value = "1"
```

then trace it through your Repository, then down to your Observer. Hopefully this will help you.